# If $B^3 = O$ does it mean that $B = O$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Let $B$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Does $B^3 = O_n$ imply $B = O_n$? If so, why?

Comment: Not true when $n>1$. Look up "nilpotent matrix" from your textbook or from the internet.

Comment: Thanks, Didn't learn that yet.

Comment: Put all entries zero, except for the one in the top right corner.

Comment: I suppose that $B_n$ is a $n\times n$-matrix. Did you mean $N=n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, take the matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix}0 &\ldots &0 &1 &0 \\
\vdots & & &0 &1 \\
\vdots & & & &0 \\
\vdots & & & &\vdots \\
0 &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots &0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: For $n=2$ or $n\ge 2$ we can take $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ for your example (which is for $n>2$).

Comment: @DietrichBurde how can we take his example for $n \ge 2$? I can't read your comment.